# static file not found after deploy not in a root dir (nextjs)

Tags: next.js

I deploy my nextjs web in a not root dir like '/next' not '/';
after that the static files in public floder can not be found.
Because the url that request is not http://example.com/next/a.png but the 
http://example.com/a.png

how can i config it to make it request 'http://example.com/next/a.png'
pls help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`assetPrefix`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/cdn-support-with-asset-prefix) feature to specify your additional dir.

```js
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  // Use the CDN in production and localhost for development.
  assetPrefix: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/next/' : '',
}
```